# Lightning strike fractal formula

Tags: fractals

I need to generate random gold ore channels for a game, I was thinking they would look kinda like lightning strikes. Anyone know any good fractals (recursive functions) that looks like it? Or otherwise methods to generate curves that are crooked, not too straight or circular. (A last resort would be to use splines and use low resolution for a bunch of short straight lines).

Answer (score 7):

> Chris LaPointe, Devin Stiert. "Volume Lightning Rendering and
>   Generation Using [L-Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system)." RPI. 2009.
>   ([PDF download](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~cutler/classes/advancedgraphics/S09/final_projects/lapointe_stiert.pdf).)

---

[image: Fig9Lightning]

---